# How to sort a list of arrays of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

Here is the script

```
use strict;

sub sortF {
my $l1 = hex ${@$a}[0];
my $l2 = hex ${@$b}[0];
return $l1 <=> $l2;
}

my @results;

my @parsedLine = ['0x1a',"hello"];
push(@results, @parsedLine);

my @parsedLine2 = ['0x1b',"ohello"];
push(@results, @parsedLine2);

my @sortedresults = sort(sortF(@results));
```

I want to sort the list @results by the first element of the anonymous array pointed to by the list elements

This give the error

```
Can't use string ("0") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at ...
```

How should the sortF function be written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make a number of small mistakes in your use of references, you should take a look at [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlsort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) for details of what to do:

```
use strict;

sub sortF {
    my $l1 = hex $a->[0]; # just use $arrayref->[index]
    my $l2 = hex $b->[0];
    return $l1 <=> $l2;
}

my @results;

my @parsedLine = ('0x1a',"hello"); # use () to make a list
push(@results, \@parsedLine); # but push an array ref

# or create an anon array ref with [] and push it immediately
push(@results, ['0x1b',"ohello"]); 

# here use the `sort SUBNAME LIST' syntax
my @sortedresults = sort sortF @results;

print join(":", map {$_->[1]} @sortedresults), "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `sortF` right here:

```
my @sortedresults = sort(sortF(@results));
```

when you mean to tell [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) to use `sortF` as the comparison function:

```
my @sortedresults = sort sortF @results;
```

What you're doing is first calling `sortF(@results)` and handing the result of that function call to `sort`. But both `$a` and `$b` will be empty inside `sortF` because `sort` hasn't set them up, that means that both `$l1` and `$l2` will be empty and `$l1 <=> $l2` will be zero. So your

```
my @sortedresults = sort(sortF(@results));
```

becomes:

```
my @sortedresults = sort(0);
```

and that's where the error message comes from.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the problem [mentioned by mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801720/how-to-sort-a-list-of-arrays-of-arrays/7801757#7801757), `${@$a}[0]` doesn't do what you probably think it does: it tries to use the *size* of the array `@$a` as an array reference, generating the warning you see.  What I assume you meant is `$a->[0]` (or `$$a[0]` if you like old-style dereferencing syntax).

Also, `my @parsedLine = ['0x1a',"hello"];` doesn't do quite what you seem to think it does either: it creates a one-element array containing a reference to an array of two strings.  This doesn't actually matter here (when you push an array onto another, all the elements are pushed in sequence), but it might bite you later.